# Search for partial match and case insensitive in django_filters

Tags: python, django

In my **filters.py** I have a filter:

```
class myFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model= bdMuebles
        fields = ["Type","Code","Name"]
```

and in **views.py** I have:

```
def vwMuebles(request):
    vrMuebles=bdMuebles.objects.all()
    vrFiltroMbl=myFilter(request.GET,queryset=vrMuebles)
    vrMuebles=vrFiltroMbl.qs
    return render(request,"MyApp/Muebles.html",{
        "dtMuebles":vrMuebles,
        "dtFiltroMbl": vrFiltroMbl,
    })
```

My question is: How can **myfilter** search for partial matches with case insensitive, ie, if type app it gives

- MyApp
- Application
- Apple

Comment: Have you tried Q lookups in django? here's an example, https://github.com/danielhasan1/blogPost/blob/5b9691b75e41cfc26521b69872fddf867582924d/posts/views.py#L84

Comment: @DanishHasan I'm very very new at django so I don't know what that is, but I'm gonna research it. Thank for the fast response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, changing **myfilter** fix it

```
class ftMuebles(django_filters.FilterSet):
    Type= django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='contains')
    Code= django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='contains')
    Name= django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='contains')
    class Meta:
        model= bdMuebles
        fields = ["Type", "Code", "Name"]
```